Why does format-number not work in xslt function?
My code
<xsl:template name="sumScorest">
  <xsl:param name="pListt"/>
  <xsl:param name="pAccumt" select="0"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$pListt">
      <xsl:variable name="vHeadt" select="$pListt[1]"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="sumScorest">
        <xsl:with-param name="pListt" select="$pListt[position()1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pAccumt" select="$pAccumt + number(substring-before(substring-after($vHeadt,'*'),'#'))"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pAccumt"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

where I call the code
  <xsl:call-template name="sumScorest">
    <xsl:with-param name="pListt" select="//n1:DespatchAdvice/cac:DespatchLine/cac:Item/cbc:Description"/>
  </xsl:call-template>

The output is a number like this (8795,885558844877), I want there to be 2 digits after the decimal point. I also want the number to be output with a thousands separator (8.795,88).

The code you are showing does not use the format-number() function anywhere. Please provide a [mcve].

I have this in my codes <xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." NaN=""/>
but when I use "format-number" instead of "number" my page does not open,

You should only use format-number where you want to finally output a formatted number, certainly not in computations like computing the sum.

this is the place you mentioned then but when I use it here the result is "0"
<xsl:call-template name="sumScorest">
<xsl:with-param name="pListt" select="format-number(//n1:DespatchAdvice/cac:DespatchLine/cac:Item/cbc:Description,'###.##0,00', 'european')"/>
</xsl:call-template>

Try changing:
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$pAccumt"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>

to:
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($pAccumt, '#.##0,00', 'european')"/>
</xsl:otherwise>


@ozsubasi Aren't you going to accept the answer?
